# jquery datatable in mvc 5

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have small problem, my pagination seems to not working.

[image]

my code is as follows:

```
`<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({


        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false, // Disable the auto width calculation
        "aoColumns": [
          { "sWidth": "10%" }, // 1st column width
          { "sWidth": "20%" }, // 2nd column width
          { "sWidth": "20%" }, // 3rd column width and so on
          { "sWidth": "20%" },
          { "sWidth": "10%" }
        ]
    });
});
</script>`
```

In my Content/Site.css I've created a class:

```
table.display {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
clear: both;
border-collapse: collapse;
table-layout: fixed;          
word-wrap:break-word;         
}
```

updated: my HTML code:

```
@using MVC.Controllers
@using DataAccess
@model IEnumerable<DataAccess.AView>

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table id="example" class="display">
@*class="table table-striped table-bordered"*@
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.ClientName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employee.NameSurname)
        </th>
        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.ClientName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employee1.NameSurname)
        </th>

        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Client.ClientName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventType.Event)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee1.NameSurname)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new {id = item.ViewID})">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                </a>
                |
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new {id = item.ViewID})">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                </a>
                |
                <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new {id = item.ViewID})">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Everything is just fine, including my widths, but pagination is missing.
Thanks,

Comment: can you show the html for the table?  Datatables is quite picky about the table being properly formatted in order for all of the features to work properly

Comment: @rogerdeuce please check my updated post.Thanks.

Comment: idk if this will solve the issue, but it looks like in the footer section instead of `<th>` you should be using `<td>` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tfoot.asp

Comment: also have you double checked that the css for datatables is reachable?

Comment: I've tried also with <td> and nothing happens.. css is reacheable, I can clearly see the difference in design..

Comment: Is the issue you are having the fact that your pagination is showing up as the blue hyperlink in your picture, or does the pagination not navigate to the next page?